# Why don't military spaceships use blockchain technology for ship log?

Tags: technology, spaceships, communication, military

Straight to the point, cut out the backstory:

If blockchain is so secure and difficult to hack why don't the military spaceship use it for logging important and also non essential events, navigation, message transactions and operation of the vessel?

Comment: Anyway backstory isn't relevant at all, especially mine... Google analytics show that my backstory is doing more harm than good

Comment: Look at it the other direction. What problems does blockchain solve to a single ship that might be solved more easily using other methods? For example, why are these military spaceships so insecure and easily hackable in the first place? Also, what good is a blockchain with (effectively) a single node?

Comment: If I may flip this around: what good is block chain?  What does it really do for you?  Other than Bitcoin, blockchain has been a solution looking for problems for about a decade now.

Comment: @CortAmmon: data structure is append only so the older entries cannot be amended and it is time stamped for back tracking, everything is secured without 3rd parties and best of all transparency and not own by 1 individual. Basically the military must be blind to overlook all these factors.

Comment: @user6760 but you can get the same without blockchain. There are secure logging practices that do pretty much the same. You essentially create a chain of logs. For simplicity, let's say each entry gets a key which is then used to derive the key for the next entry. The key is also based on content. If you're familiar with how Git commits work, it's not too dissimilar to how commit hashes and linking them works. In essence, you can't have a log entry in the middle tampered with, removed, or added without disrupting the chain of keys for logs.

Comment: @VLAZ: currently the military is researching on directed acyclic graphic and work in still in progress... But most commercial are adopting blockchain at an exponential rate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to be mainly about understanding a technology and its possible applications. There's other stacks dedicated to this very dubject that can provide better and more thorough answers than we could ever want.

Comment: If you don't want information to be hacked, consider paper.

Comment: Blockchain is overhyped. Also, it grows stronger the wider it's spread, while you don't want to spread your military data everywhere, even encrypted. It's also really expensive in both money and energy to maintain.

Comment: This question shows a complete lack of understanding of what block chain technology is for. Block chain technology is intended only and only for maintaining the integrity of a distributed database where the parties hosting the database do not trust each other. It has no applicability to maintaining the integrity of a centrally managed database. Voting to close as showing insufficient research.

Comment: @user6760 They must not be blind to overlook those factors, but they also aren't obliged to be enamored with them either.  When you trust your fellow man with holding a firearm because they're going to have your back when you need it most, some algorithmic approaches to "trust" are less valuable.  And the single points of failure that can command a forgery to take place?  They're entrusted with the lives of thousands.

Comment: http://doyouneedablockchain.com/

Comment: Simple answer: because most writers (and readers) don't know what blockchain is, other than a buzzword.

Comment: The question remains closed, so I can't add an answer, but I can answer the newly edited question.  Blockchain provides its integrity guarantees in the absence of a centralized system to provide integrity.  If you have such a centralized system, there are far better ways to provide security.  The military has such centralized systems. (Indeed, the failure of many "blockchain" vaporware products is that they relied on a centralized source of integrity, making the entire blockchain aspect pointless)

Answer (score 7):

Blockchains only make sense when you need to ensure the integrity of, well, a *chain*.

In the most general case, the way a blockchain works is that each block contains a data payload, and a verification hash, which is a fixed-size summary of

1. The payload of this block, and
2. The entirety of the preceding block.

Because the hash of the preceding block was based on the entirety of the block before that, and so on, the hash for any given block depends on the payloads of all previous blocks. That means it is very difficult to alter a block far back in the chain, because you would have to update every subsequent block as well. The older a block is, the harder it is to alter. However, newer blocks are *easy* to alter, and it is *easy* to produce alternate histories (essentially producing a block *tree*), and using a blockchain in an of itself is no defense against hacking. Blockchain applications (like, say, Bitcoin) thus all require some additional method of establishing concensus on what the most recent block is, because the security of a blockchain depends on age and there is *no* inherent protection on that most recent block. Additionally, a lot of the security of, e.g., Bitcoin, also depends on the distributed nature of the particular blockchain in use; if the data is spread over hundreds or thousands of different clients, it becomes completely impractical to alter the data on >50% of them; but if you are dealing with a localized log, it is much easier to rewrite a huge chunk of history to account for whatever changes you might want to make to a single old block.

So, if you want to ensure that nothing has been removed from old logs, then using a blockchain data structure might be one component of the security measures for your ship's log--but it would be *stupid* to make it the *only* security measure, and other approaches to data integrity make blockchain largely superfluous in those circumstances.

Comment: Incidentally, you just *also* described the data inegrity mechanism of version control systems such as [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git). Really, if you want to ensure log integrity, you'd be pretty dumb to *not* use something like that. (Not necessarily as the *only* measure, as noted, but it's a *useful* measure that's dead simple to employ.)

Comment: @Matthew Indeed I did! But you'll note that git fully embraces the tree structure. It makes no attempt to enforce a unique chain structure. And it even includes methods of intentionally re-writing history. So, if you need a reason to *not* use blockchain, it's perfectly reasonable to just say "we don't *need* to, 'cause the stuff we *do* need already has that covered", even if it is simple. Especially if you don't actually care about chain integrity (say, if you are transmitting logs over an unreliable channel and require resyncing), just individual document integrity.

Comment: @Matthew git and most blockchains are built on the same underlying principle, the Merkle tree. Its no surprise they look similar.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley git, like blockchains, is just a means of tracking history. Sure, you can fork the structure and fiddle with it as much as you like, but you cannot do so without people noticing and if you want your version of history to become _everyone's_ version of history, you need to reach consensus. The differences are minimal compared to the similarities.

Comment: @StarfishPrime People will only notice if you actually have distributes storage--just like a blockchain. And again, the means of reaching consensus is *independent* of the hash-chaining technology. If you use git's mechanism, then it remains easy to hack--people may notice that there were changes, but they won't be able to tell if they were legitimate or not.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley legitimacy is conferred by consensus in either case. Blockchains tend to have a more formal mechanism for conferring consensus, such as "_the one who can afford the most chinese hydropower gets to decide which transaction history is acceptable_". With changes to a git repo, you _still_ have to convince everyone that your changes are legitimate, and if they believe you then it becomes so. You could do this via digitally signing your commits, though this is generally too much hassle to be worth it for _most_ developers and teams.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes. And my whole point is that that consensus protocol is entirely independent of the hash chaining technology.  You can have either one without the other. Thus, if all you want is hard-to-manipulate consensus on whether a log entry is accurate, there is no particular reason to use blockchain.

Answer (score 6):

In practice, the reason they don't use blockchain is the same reason they don't use vacuum tubes. By the time you're thinking in terms of military spaceships, blockchain will be some forgotten old reference only of interest to those studying the history of computing.

Be very careful putting fine detail on the cutting edge of present technology in a future scenario.

Comment: People too enamoured of the technological or social trends of the day find their work seriously afflicted by [zeerust](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Zeerust). Seems like it should be obvious, but...

Answer (score 5):

Well, as a programmer, I can easily give you two reasons.

First, it would be extremely difficult to modify data in the log. Say your hypothetical "Cpt. Kirk" gets pissed at the science officer (let's call him "Spock") while inebriated. He then puts an extremely ill-thought-out entry in our hypothetical log, saying some... ah... unprintable things about "Spock". Later he decides he wants to delete the entry, forcing his sysadmin ("Scotty") to spend three days removing the entry from the log. When the ship (the "Enterprise") gets back to base Murphy's Law kicks in, causing "Kirk's" superiors ("Starfleet") to find the one reference that "Scotty" missed. As a result, "Kirk" is reprimanded for his ill-thought-through actions, and "Scotty" is court-martialed for tampering with the log. While in theory a log should not be modified, in reality a captain probably does not want embarrassing or fallacious data in there.

On the other hand, there is no reason to use blockchain in the first place, as "Cpt. Kirk" would almost definately be required to keep an analog back-up in his safe.

On the same note, plain encryption is probably a better option, as while blockchains *do* get some of their security from being hard to modify, it is actually this spread out over several separate computers all operating at once that gives blockchain its security. That is why cryptocurrencies pay people to use their computers as transaction-recorders, instead of just getting one big supercomputer.

EDIT: Kudos to @LoganR.Kearsley for pointing out that packet size does not go up over time.

Comment: Clearly the ship's log needs one of those "are you sober enough to do math" authenticators Google added to their email.

Comment: The entries do not need to contain the data from all previous entries; they just contain a hash of all of the previous entries' data, which is constant in size.

Comment: @Cadence: I was just using that as an example. Irregardless, yes: they do need a sobriety test.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley :  My mistake. When I was taught to program blockchains they did not say to do hashes. I guess I need to look up some newer tutorials.

Comment: @thescribe "Irregardless" isn't a word. :)  *Regardless*, the point of a ship's log is that it isn't modified.  The captain's own log is a personal record which can be as explicit as they want, secure in the knowledge that it won't be read by anyone else unless the captain is already dead (or arrested for something else, perhaps).  But the ship's own log should be as near impossible to change as is possible.  Yes, that probably means it will include recordings of the original assemblers going "one-two, is this thing on?" and that's by design.

Comment: Your Star Trek story is an example of why immutability is a _good_ thing all round.. (good for Starfleet, good for Scotty, and _good for Spock_ - it will also make Kirk think twice before hitting "Send" and is therefore good for him too)

Comment: @Graham It _is_ a word, and has been since 1795, even if you aren't a fan of it :)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica : Two things. (1): Thanks for backing me up on "Irregardless". (2): I was just using that as an example to point out that sometimes a captain might want to change the log. In reality, he would usually change it if, say, he discovers that the sensors were malfunctioning, putting fallacious information in the log.

Comment: @Graham : That's interesting that you say that, as its right there on pp. 714 of "Webster’s New World Dictionary (Third College Edition)"

Comment: @thescribe Quoting the Wikipedia summary, "Most dictionaries list it as non-standard or incorrect usage, and recommend that "regardless" should be used instead." :) That aside though, back to the log. Those fallacious sensor readings are *more* important, because they tell us how the sensors failed and what the captain did about it. As with an aircraft black box, faults are more important than normal running. My point is that there can never be a case where a captain should be allowed to change the log, any more than an airline pilot should be allowed to turn off the black box recorder.

Comment: If we were religiously deferential to "most dictionaries", @Graham, we wouldn't have such excellent words as "cromulent" in increasing usage. Indeed, if we all worshipped at the altar of prescriptivism, language _wouldn't exist at all_ (chicken meet egg). Be less boring :)

Comment: @thescribe But we don't want him to be able to change the log. :)

Answer (score 4):

Blockchain tech is about maintaining integrity across a distributed system, which is why it's used for decentralised transaction processing. Every node in the system has to agree on the history and what the definitive version of the blockchain is, which can be a pretty laborious task - one of the reasons Bitcoin's network has trouble processing the kind of transaction rates it's been seeing in boom times.

It doesn't really help if you're maintaining logs on your ship's computer in a situation where your ability to communicate with HQ is limited, because you can rewrite a blockchain relatively easily provided nobody else has seen it yet. Once other parties have seen the chain, any different version you try to push will be obviously different, but until you've transmitted it to base you can merrily rewrite it as much as you like.

Of course, the logs could be distributed within the spacecraft's systems, but given that the engineers on board probably include a few computer specialists capable of dismantling the system software right down to the lowest level and rebuilding it, that is unlikely to prove too much obstacle to a crew really motivated to alter their logs. If the crew doesn't have people like that on board, good luck dealing with a software bug you find when you're 45 light years from home and your hyperdrive won't boot up.

Answer (score 3):

What evidence do you have that they do not?

If blockchain protection becomes the standard way to protect and insure important documents and everybody has access to it and uses it as a matter of course, then it just wouldn't be mentioned by narrator or character. Just as you would usually not say that someone wrote "with a ballpoint pen", or wore "leather shoes".

Blockchain would only be mentioned in a story if someone had a reason for not using it while everyone else was.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain is only "secure" and "difficult to hack" when it's distributed over a lot of systems. The "truth" in a blockchain system is the truth most of the systems which calculate the blockchain agree on.

So if you want to manipulate a blockchain, you need to hack over 50% of the systems to have the whole system assume a new truth and hack 100% to destroy all evidence that a manipulation might have taken place.

As you can see, using a blockchain on a single system gives you no security at all.

Answer (score -1):

### Energy consumption

Blockchain is HUGELY energy intensive (it was estimated that Bitcoin's annual carbon emission is 20-22 Million Tonnes - which, if it were a nation would equal carbon emissions of Sri Lanka).

Based on Moore's law, due to the increase of processing power, modern day cryptographic algorithms have to keep adding more bits to their moduli in order to increase the brute force protection. (it costs significantly cheaper to brute-force a SHA-1 today than it did five years ago).

In the future, processing power would be significantly higher, meaning significantly higher moduli for encryption (think SHA-32768). From a real-time perspective, encryption of these payloads is the same, but from an energetic perspective, the cost to decrypt the numerical data of the payload is HUGE. This would result in an explosion of energy demands for performing ledger-signing for very trivial things, thus would not be deemed necessary.

Comment: The reason why Bitcoin is so energy intensive is that it has a bunch of nodes that are handling complex calculations. The single-node energy costs are actually rather small; you can run a highly energy-efficient Raspberry Pi as a node without even having to overclock it.